# Generate all words from an alphabet

Tags: list, haskell, sequence

I'd like to generate all words from a given alphabet. For example:

```
['a', 'b'] -> ["","a","b","aa","ba","ab","bb","aaa","baa","aba","bba","aab" ...]
```

I manage to implement this function by now:

```
myfunc :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
myfunc l = iterate fromList $ map (\x -> x : []) l
  where
    fromList ls = [y : ys | y <- l, ys <- ls]
```

But this function doesn't generate the result correctly. I want the answer to be a String to take for example only the first 5 elements -> `["","a","b","aa","ba"]`. Any help how to do that?

Comment: @melpomene: I think the OP does not mean sublist. They want to generate *all* possible sequences consisting out of the alphabet `"ab"`.

Comment: yes .. my mistake sorry .. I changed the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example you do *not* generate sublists: you generate *sequences* of string from the given alphabet `l`.

Furthermore the signature of `myfunc` should be `[a] -> [[a]]`. Indeed the elements of the list are strings as well, so `[a]`s.

You can use **recursive** list comprehension for that:

```
myfunc :: [a] -> [[a]]
myfunc l = []:[(x:ys) | ys <- myfunc l, x <- l]
```

Which generates:

```
*Main> take 10 $ myfunc "ab"
["","a","b","aa","ba","ab","bb","aaa","baa","aba"]
```

The code works as follows, the first element we emit is the empty string (the `[]` part in the `[]:...`). So this will be the first result we emit (but also the first in the recursive result).

Now in the list comprehension part, we iterate over all elements of `myfunc l` (so first `ys` is the empty list), and we prepend that element with all characters of the alphabet (`a` and `b`). Next `ys` will be `[a]` and so we prepend the characters of the alpabeth with that, and so on.

Comment: I didn't see that ... Thanks for help and for the solution.